# Div just disappears when include a .php file

Tags: php, css, html

OK so basically the problem is in the title. I believe it is with the first file because as soon as it is included the footer div just vanishes when it it shouldn't.

I have been through all of the attaching php files and I strongly believe it is the first include that brings this problem to the code.

```
<?php


        $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT active FROM profilepage WHERE username='$u'") or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die ("$u not found");
        $a_check = $row['active'];

        if($u != $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check == 0 or $u != $log_username && $user_ok != true && $a_check == 0) {
            echo "Sorry this person hasn't activated a video feed yet"; 
            mysqli_close($db_conx);
            exit;
            }

        else if($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check == 0) {
                include_once("acti-button.php");
                mysqli_close($db_conx);
                    exit(); 
                }


        else if ($u != $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1 or $u != $log_username && $user_ok != true && $a_check == 1 or $u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1) {
            include_once("showcase.php");
            mysqli_close($db_conx);
            exit(); 
            }




        ?>
```

Above is the .php include called `activate-or-view.php` and any out come it has makes the footer div disappear.

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
?>
<div id="pageMiddle">
    <div id="banner_pic_box"><?php echo $banner_pic_btn; ?><?php echo $banner_form; ?><?php echo $banner_pic; ?></div>
        <div id="midright">
            <div id="username"><?php echo $u; ?></div>
            <div id="profile_pic_box"><?php echo $profile_pic_btn; ?><?php echo $avatar_form; ?><?php echo $profile_pic; ?></div>
            <span id="friendBtn"><?php echo $friend_button; ?></span><span id="blockBtn"><?php echo $block_button; ?></span><br>
                <div id="about">Owner of page? <b><?php echo $isOwner; ?></b><br>
                    Gender: <?php echo $sex; ?><br>
                    Country: <?php echo $country; ?><br>
                    User Level: <?php echo $userlevel; ?><br>
                    Join Date: <?php echo $joindate; ?><br>
                    Last Session: <?php echo $lastsession; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $user_you. $friend_count." friends"; ?><?php echo $friends_view_all_link; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $friendsHTML; ?><br>
                </div>
        </div>
    <div id="midmid"><?php include_once("profile_interface/videob/activate-or-view.php"); ?></div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="pageBottom"><?php include_once("profile_interface/templates/default/template_pageBottom.php"); ?></div>
```

The above code is the content.php file is. I do not normally keep the fotter here and is normally on the user page but it doesn't matter where it is so I thought I should keep it here for the time being so I do not have to post loads of code. Can I just add that on the user.php file that the `</bod>` and `</html>` tags do exist at the bottom of the page.

```
<?php // This is a user count for total activated members on the website. Can be used for Teams, Profiles, Commentators, Tournaments and Providers

     $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE activated='1'";
     $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
     $usercount = $row[0];
?>

&copy;2014 The War Room
<br />Total Users: <?php echo $usercount; ?>
```

The above code is the actually foot what disappears when I add the include above it. Can I also add that it doesn't matter what `div` is below the include because they all just disappear when it is added. I believe it is the first include and not the rest of the module that does it because of the fact it doesn't matter what the out come is of the first include all `div`'s below it simple vanish.

```
body { margin: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; }

    /* Page Top e.g. Header/Menu */
    #pageTop {
         background:url(headersliver.png) repeat-x;
         height: 90px;
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap {
         width: 1000px;
         margin: 0px auto;
         height: 90px;
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopLogo {
         float: left;
         margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
         height: 80px;
         width: 174px;
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest {
         float: left;
         height: 90px;
         width: 826px;
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu1 {
         height: 44px;

        }   
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu1 > div {
         margin-top: 10px;
         padding: 4px;
         text-align:right;
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu1 > div > a {
         color: #ffffff;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-size: 16px;        
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu1 > div > a:hover {
         color: #66a3d2;
         }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu2 {
         height: 44px;

        }       
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu2 > div {
         margin-top: 2px;
         padding: 4px;
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu2 > div > a {
         display: block;
         float: left;
         color: #ffffff;
         text-decoration: none;
         margin: 0px 10px; 
        }
    #pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest > #menu2 > div > a:hover {
         color: #66a3d2;

        }
    /* Page Middle e.g Main Content*/   
    #pageMiddle {
         width: 1000px;
         margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #pageMiddle > #about{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}


     #pageMiddle > #midleft {
     width: 240px;
     margin: 0px;

}
     #pageMiddle > #midmid {
     width: 800px;
     margin: 0px;
     float: left;
     margin-right:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
     #pageMiddle > #midright {
     width: 200px;
     float: right;
     margin: 0px;

}
#pageMiddle >#midright > #about{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
}

     #pageMiddle > #midright > #username{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 55px;
        background: #464444;
        color: #2a77bb;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #FFF;
        margin: 0px;



}

    /* Page Bottom e.g Copyright bar*/
    #pageBottom {
         background: #464444;
         padding: 24px;
         font-size: 12px;
         color: #CCC;
         text-align: center;
    }
```

The above is my CSS file. This file is included on the user.php file and has no problem loading on the page however could it be something in here what is making the `div`'s disappear? At the bottom you will find the code for the footer div.

If anyone could help me out I would appreciate it a lot as I have been stump on this for hours and simply do not know what to do. Could it be my CSS? When I do checks on w3 it comes back saying that there are unclosed `div`'s. There are no `div`'s within the module it self and are all on the content code what is the 2nd code I posted.

Thank you for reading this and I hope you can help.

Comment: echo include_once("showcase.php"); ....why the echo??

Comment: I was testing to see what was the problem. I have forgotten to remove. I have now removed it.

Comment: And if you remove the 2 exit(); on the first file?

Comment: eliminate the include from the equation. copy the full contents of the  included file in replacement of your include()s.

Comment: I have tried that. I will try it again tho

Comment: I have just put the whole lot into user.php and nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the various calls to `exit()`.  It will [terminate the script](https://www.php.net/exit), so nothing after it will be executed. Thus, the footer is never processed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have just removed all `exit();`'s but nothing has changed thank you once again for helping

Comment: mmm. just done it again. It seems to have half worked now. except there is a error and the fact the footer div is also behind the midmid dive. The good news is that it is now loading so at least I can see it and now solve the other issues. Thank you for you help

Comment: Thank you ever so much. with you help i was able to get the problem stamped out. I will not be making the exit mistake again. I will only use it for behind scene reasons.